# can't install office 2013 on wine

Tags: linux, wine

whenever I try to install office 2013 I get this error at the end

```
0140:fixme:msi:MsiEndTransaction 0
```

and yes I have created a 32 bit wine prefix for office 2013 and my wine version is `wine-7.15`
I would appreciate it a lot if you help me

Comment: According to this https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26323 it ostensibly should work. You're welcome to post a bug report here: https://bugs.winehq.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Wine

Comment: okay I filed the bug hope they reply fast